# banshee-extension-coverwallpaper is not working

Tags: banshee, extension

I have installed the user-extension-pack for banshee, including the Coverwallpaper-extension. Everything else is working as is should, but althoug I activated Cover Wallpaper at the extension-Tab in the settings-window, my background isn't changing. What should I do?

Comment: If you also have the lyrics plugin enabled, disable it and try again. Else it's probably best to file a bug report ([instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)).